# Table/Columns names with Pascal Casing

Tags: database-design

I am new to Oracle.

1. I have all the table/Column names in Upper Case and with Underscores in DB2. We are planning to convert to Oracle and in Pascal Casing and removing Underscores (table/Column names only). How does that effect PL/SQL developers in writing SQLs.Do we have to specify everytime the table name with "".
2. How do i convert these in Erwin Naming standards.

Answer (score 0):

In PL/SQL, you can specify the database.

```
use db_name;
```

Once you specify the database, you do not need to use it again. What naming convention you use does not affect the PL/SQL performance. Conventions are for our understanding.

I did not understand completely what you mean by

> specify everytime the table name with "".

If you mean by double quotes, then no. Oracle does not need double quotes.

You can find more stuff in the manual for your version of Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have started naming objects enclosed them in double quotes, and having the names not in uppercase, you will need to keep doing so. By default Oracle will convert to uppercase any string not enclosed in double quotes.

e.g. if you have the statement:

```
Create Table "MyTable" ("MyIdentifier" Number(10), "MyText" Varchar2(100));
```

you would then need to use source code statements such as:

```
Select "MyText" From "MyTable" Where "MyIdentifier" = 1;
```

However, if you do not use double quotes when creating objects the object names will actually be in uppercase and your source code can conform to your standards without the need for double quotes e.g.

```
Create Table MyTable (MyIdentifier Number(10), MyText Varchar2(100));
Select MyText From MyTable Where MyIdentifier = 1;
```